# Как заменить значение времени в строке, полученной из input time?

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с задачей, в которой из `input` с типом `time` я извлекаю `value` в виде строки, например, "17:00", и мне нужно преобразовать ее в другие значения с интервалом в N минут, предположим прибавить 90 минут и получить несколько значений (18:30, 20:00, 21:30 и т.д), чтобы вернуть их в html и отобразить на странице.

Понимаю, что вопрос элементарный, но своими силами решить пока что не получается, и  статью на эту тему не могу найти.

Comment: Информация есть - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes (прибавить минут), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time (общая инфа по `input[type="time"]`). В чем суть трудностей и вопроса?

Comment: Возможно, суть трудностей с прибавлением минут прояснит дополнение вопроса минимальным кодом.

Comment: Пока что не писал код, пробовал настроить логику в консоли самого браузера. 
В упрощенном виде, представим, что это выглядит так: https://codepen.io/CookHook/pen/WNNdgWO
Юзер вводит желаемое время, нужно написать функцию, которая возьмет значение time, например, 17:00, прибавит к нему 90 минут (это число буду прописывать я сам, а не юзер), и на выходе в поле result мы должны увидеть значение 18:30.
То есть, если я правильно понимаю, нужно разделить строку "17:00" на часы и минуты, прибавить к часам 1, к минутам 30, затем собрать это в строку 18:30 и поменять textContent.

Comment: Если хочется пойти сложным и долгим путем, то можно и через строки - но я все-таки советую посмотреть ссылки в первом комментарии, и работать с временем через тип `Date` (используя свойство `valueAsDate`).

Comment: Код желательно оставлять в теле вопроса, а не в комментариях на сторонние ресурсы. Так больше вероятности получить ответ, а не минусы и закрытие вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с `valueAsDate` (будет работать прямо во время ввода):

```js
let demo = document.querySelectorAll('.demo');
let input = document.getElementById('input-time');

input.addEventListener('input', function(){
  let time = this.valueAsDate;

  console.clear();
  console.log( "valueAsDate: " + time );
  
  demo[0].textContent = "+90 — " + addMinutes(time, 90);
  demo[1].textContent = "-90 — " +  addMinutes(time, -90);
  demo[2].textContent = "+300 — " +  addMinutes(time, 300);
});

function addMinutes(time, mins) {
  let d = new Date( time.getTime() + mins * 60000 );
  return [
    addZero( d.getUTCHours() ),
    addZero( d.getUTCMinutes() ),
  ].join(":");
}

function addZero(n) { return n > 9 ? n : "0" + n; }
```

```html
<input id="input-time" type="time" value="18:30">
<p class="demo"></p>
<p class="demo"></p>
<p class="demo"></p>
```

Вариант со строками:

```js
let demo = document.querySelectorAll('.demo');
let input = document.getElementById('input-time');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  let time = this.value;

  demo[0].textContent = "+90 — " + addMinutes(time, 90);
  demo[1].textContent = "-90 — " + addMinutes(time, -90);
  demo[2].textContent = "+300 — " + addMinutes(time, 300);
});

function addMinutes(time, mins) {
  mins = mins % 1440; // Если передали очень много минут - отбросить лишние дни.
  let addM = + mins % 60; // Отбросили все целые '60', остались только минуты
  let addH = (mins - addM) / 60;
  
  let [hh, mm] = time.split(":");
  
  let m = +mm + addM;
  let extraHour = 0;
  if ( m > 59 ){ // пример: 50 + 30 = 80 минут
    extraHour = (m - (m = m % 60)) / 60;
          // = (80 -(20 = 80 % 60)) / 60
       // в процессе ↑ m становится 20, (80 - 20) / 60 == 1 час
  } else if ( m < 0 ){
    extraHour = -1;
  }
  
  let h = (+hh + extraHour + addH + 24) % 24;
  // Лишний +24 на случай, если часы отрицательные.
  
  return addZero(h) + ":" + addZero( (m + 60) % 60 ); // +60 % 60 для отрицательных минут
}

function addZero(n) { return n > 9 ? n : "0" + n; }
```

```html
<input id="input-time" type="time" value="18:30">
<p class="demo"></p>
<p class="demo"></p>
<p class="demo"></p>
```